# Ubuntu doesnt boot after swapping my Gpu

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics, gpu

I swapped my r7 260x for an rx 6600xt and hoped that it would work fine , since both cards are from amd, but when I try to boot it just shows the motherboard splash screen until I force shutdown. It works fine on windows , so the card seems to work. I still have the old card , are there possible solutions to this?

(I have no clue how drivers work on linux , any help would be nice :D ty)

Comment: Should we assume the test you did, in Windows, was in a different machine?

Comment: I am dualbooting , it was on the same machine

Comment: I also tried a live bootable usb and that worked fine too , but it was a newer version of ubuntu i think

Comment: If so, "it just shows the motherboard splash screen" makes no sense. The motherboard's splash screen appears before, not after, Grub. Or are you booting Windows via UEFI boot menu? If so it suggests the installed Ubuntu is in Legacy mode which in itself is a problem already.

Comment: No it really is like that , i can make a photo if you want. But youre right, this does seem really weird

Comment: So you're saying the **motherboard's** splash screen appears AFTER selecting Ubuntu in Grub menu but it doesn't if you select Windows? Which Ubuntu release/version, BTW?

Comment: Im not sure since I didnt check before swapping the gpu , but I think it was 20.04